# Why are Bench module's "wallclock" seconds report so wildly off?

Tags: raku

I'm benchmarking this code:

```
use Bench;
my $b = Bench.new;
say 'start';
my $i=0;
$b.timethese(100000, {
    first => sub { while $i++ < 10000 { }   },
    second => sub { while $i++ < 10000 { }  }
});
```

I get this report:

```
Timing 100000 iterations of first, second...
     first: 2.105 wallclock secs (1.786 usr 0.449 sys 2.235 cpu) @ 47502.644/s (n=100000)
    second: 2.341 wallclock secs (2.012 usr 0.445 sys 2.458 cpu) @ 42710.876/s (n=100000)
```

So about 4.5 "wallclock" seconds total. But by my stopwatch, it's is taking around 19 seconds. What accounts for this?

Comment: Loading the interpreter, compiling and garbage collecting and tear down after that, probably.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that done only once?

Comment: No, every time you run raku. Modules are precompiled, but not scripts.

Comment: So each time it runs a loop it fires up a new interpreter? That can't be right.

Comment: And when you say "module", do you mean like a full blown module or "unit Module M" name space?

Comment: "So about 4.5 "wallclock" seconds total. But by my stopwatch, it's is taking around 19 seconds. What accounts for this?" [The `Bench` module `try`s to `require` the `Telemetry` module](https://github.com/tony-o/perl6-bench/blob/683f13064ae6c9d4cd54234c4961bde8401b703d/lib/Bench.pm6#L2). It will normally succeed. If so, it will then incur the overhead of using [`Telemetry`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Telemetry). I presume that accounts for some of the difference; perhaps to get more useful and accurate *telemeterized* measurements a good deal of actual wall clock is spent on telemetry overhead.

Comment: No, every time you run the script. Wallclock seconds will include that.

Comment: But the actual real time, "wallclock" seconds are far longer than what Bench is reporting.

Comment: @StevieD I can't tell if that's a response to my comment. The actual, real time, "wallclock" seconds are, well, actual, real time, "wallclock" seconds. The "wallclock" seconds `Bench` is reporting should be what the actual, real time, "wallclock" seconds would be if `Bench` was *not* used. The difference can logically be a large amount if, when tracking performance, the mechanisms used to track performance have a lot of overhead themselves. And, aiui, this is the case for `Telemetry`. I suggest you try running the same benchmarks on the same system but *without* using `Bench`.

Answer (score 1):

Aiui:

- The `Bench` module uses¹ the [`Telemetry`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Telemetry) module.
- While `Telemetry` provides very precise measurement of performance, it introduces overhead in doing so, and that overhead can be very large compared to the time/memory consumed by the code being measured.
- The "wallclock" seconds `Bench` is reporting are what the "wallclock" seconds *would be* if the `Telemetry` overhead were not incurred.

---

¹ Or, more accurately, [`try`s to `require`](https://github.com/tony-o/perl6-bench/blob/683f13064ae6c9d4cd54234c4961bde8401b703d/lib/Bench.pm6#L2) it.